# Iterating through values in Dictionary Subclass

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class that inherits from OrderedDict. I want to be able to iterate through its values, rather than its keys.

I believe the following code should work, but it does not. Instead of printing the values "one" and "two", it gives some sort of recursion error (shown below the code).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class A(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()    

    def __iter__(self):
        for value in self.values():
            yield value
        return

a = A()
a[1] = "one"
a[2] = "two"

for thing in a:
    print str(thing)
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
File "T:\***\Test024.py", line 8, in __iter__
    for value in self.values():
File "C:\Python27\Lib\collections.py", line 111, in values
    return [self[key] for key in self]
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Why doesn't the above example work? I know I can iterate over the values with a loop like `for thing in a.values():`, but I want to avoid the inconsistency of using `.values()` for dictionaries, but not lists, for example. I do need the functionality of a dictionary in other parts of the code.

Comment: [Wrong comment] remove `return`

Comment: What's the point of doing this? One would expect a dict to return keys on iteration not values. Simply use `a.itervalues()`.

Comment: @sangheestyle That won't do anything.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Ah, you are right. But the original code works on my local. That's why I confused. Sorry.

Comment: Most of the things I iterate over are of the form `for item in set:`. Making some things `for item in set.values():` seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: Then you should be using a `set` or `list`, if you're not doing anything with keys then there's no point of using a dict here. Returning values from dict's `__iter__` will also make your code hard to understand to others.

Comment: @wim `return iter(self.values())`: This is basically the same thing as what OP is doing.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I am using keys in other places in the code, just not here.

Comment: @PProteus My point is returning values from `__iter__` is the inconsistent behaviour, no one apart from your would expect a dict to return values during its iteration. `for item in set.values()` is pretty clear and someone seeing it will know what's happening.  With that said you could do: `for k in super(A, self).__iter__(): yield self[k]` in your `__iter__` to get values.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That works! Thanks. I'm sure there is a good reason why dictionaries iterate over the keys not the values in python, but it doesn't seem consistent with behaviour for other collections. The principle of consistency would seem to indicate that lists should then iterate over their indexes, rather than their elements—which would be silly, of course.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the exception traceback, `OrderedDict.values` iterates over the dict:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py", line 123, in values
return [self[key] for key in self]
```

Since you've overriden the `__iter__` function, this results in infinite recursion.

To overcome this, you will have to override the `values` function, for example like this:

```
def values(self):
    return [self[key] for key in OrderedDict.__iter__(self)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hacky solution but by modifying the original `OrderedDict`'s implementation (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/collections.py:90`) you could do the following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class A(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def __iter__(self):
        'od.__iter__() <==> iter(od)'
        # Traverse the linked list in order.
        root = self._OrderedDict__root
        curr = root[1]
        while curr is not root:
            yield self[curr[2]]
            curr = curr[1]

a = A()
a[1] = "one"
a[2] = "two"

for thing in a:
    print str(thing)
```

When run:

```
$ ./foo.py
one
two
```